# ng-repeat - I'm confused on it works

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm pretty new to angular js and I have a question about the ng-repeat. I'm following examples at AngularJs : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

The section that I'm currently on is 'Adding UI logic: Controllers'. If you look at the index.html, specifically at the code:

```
<span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
      {{invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
    </span>
```

When I run in the browser, everything works as expected, but I notice that invoice.total function runs at least 6 times. How do I know? Well in the index.js I added a console.log function within the total function as seen here:

```
this.total = function total(outCurr){
    console.log(outCurr)
    console.log(this.convertCurrency(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr))
    return this.convertCurrency(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr);
  };
```

I would expect the code to run 3 times because the invoice.currencies only has 3 items:

```
this.currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
```

However, this is what I see in my browser console window:
[image]

Any ideas? Thank you in advance?

Comment: This might be a digest cycle while your application is being rendered.

Comment: The digest cycle runs at least twice to check that a value hasn't changed. First time it runs for each of the values in `this.currencies`. It runs again to check that the first digest cycle hasn't changed any values. It hasn't so it stops after the 2nd cycle.

Answer (score 0):

user2341963 has probably the good answer so i'll quote it first and i'll add some precision.

> The digest cycle runs at least twice to check that a value hasn't
>   changed. First time it runs for each of the values in this.currencies.
>   It runs again to check that the first digest cycle hasn't changed any
>   values. It hasn't so it stops after the 2nd cycle

In angular you have what we call a digest cycle. This cycle watch for any change that happened in the application bind to angular. In order to refresh it. This permit to refresh your DOM when you need without refreshing the whole page.

"The bind to angular" means

1. Every block between {{}}
2. Every use of scope.$watch or attrs.$observe which are used massively by directives (ng-model/ng-repeat/...).

I don't know what makes this cycle to trigger twice at start this is probably because of some internal mechanics or the filter that you use. Check this link for more info : https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/